# Updating Dependencies Xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies

I'm trying to install Codelite on Xubuntu 13.10 (I think), i'm not a "genius" of linux, so i have troubles with those dependencies that needs to be update.

I already update the system using "Software updater" in Settings.
I tried those commands that i found in internet:
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean"
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install libgcc1

but when i try to install it says always the same:

```
user@xubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install codelite
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codelite : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) but 1.3.2-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
user@xubuntu:~$
```

Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same problem. You need to update to 14.10. It resolves the dependencies. I suggest using this answer as a walk through. https://askubuntu.com/questions/541326/upgrade-xubuntu-from-14-04-to-14-10